# DataTable object is empty even though the item that it was converted from is not

Tags: c#, oracle, datatable, datagridview

I'm trying to do an update on an Oracle table from a datagridview using TableAdapter.Update() in C#. I've written the following code for this:

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(DataGridViewRow row in aNGAJATDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                ANGAJATDataTable da=new ANGAJATDataTable();
                da = row.Cells[1].Value as ANGAJATDataTable;
                if(da==null)
                    MessageBox.Show("null");
                else
                    this.aNGAJATTableAdapter.Update(da);
            }
            
        }
```

However, my **da** variable is always null, even though **row.Cells[1].Value** is not and I don't know how to fix this in order for the update to work.

I need to be able to update the information in my "ANGAJAT" table directly from the datagridview without using the method with the query, dataset and so on and this alternative was the best that I could find. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. I edited the update command from the aNGAJATTableAdapter and then used parameters in a foreach loop in order to store every cell from my datagridview.